# Manually Password Protect Files/Folders (Linux)

Tags: linux, .htaccess, .htpasswd

I want to make file/folders password protected in Linux(Centos) using **htpasswd**.
I have done following:-

```
root@ cd /mnt/Recordings/CONF (I have Changed the directory)

CONF@ htpasswd -c .htpasswd xxxxx

CONF@ pwd
/mnt/Recordings/CONF

CONF@ vim .htaccess

AuthUserFile /mnt/Recordings/CONF/ .htpasswd
AuthName "Enter Password"
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Protected Context"

<Limit GET POST>
require valid-user
Require python
</Limit>
```

I'm not able to create password protected file/folder in Linux("front end"/"command prompt"/"web based").
I got following error:

[Wed Jan 08 17:38:57 2014] [alert] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] /mnt/Recordings/CONF/.htaccess: Invalid auth file type: .htpasswd

Comment: Does your AuthUserFile contain a typo? Perhaps check AuthUserFile "/etc/htpasswd/.htpasswd" (no space, in quotes).

Answer (score 0):

Try Following code in the htaccess file:

`AuthUserFile "/mnt/Recordings/CONF/.htpasswd"
AuthType Basic
AuthName "My Secret Folder"
Require valid-user
Satisfy    any
Order      deny,allow
Deny from  all`